# Removing null warnings in Splint

Tags: c, static-analysis, syntax-checking, splint

I have been trying out [Splint](http://www.splint.org/) with a C program I recently wrote and trying to understand and remove the warnings it gives. One I understand but can't understand how to remove it comes from the following code snippet:

```
static MyType_t *findById(const int id)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MY_ARR_SIZE; i++) {
            if (my_arr[i].id == NOT_SET) {
                    /* Items are sorted so that items with 
                    NOT_SET as ID are at the end of the array */
                    break;
            }
            if (my_arr[i].id == id) {
                    return &(my_arr[i]);
            }
    }
    return NULL; 
}
```

Splint isn't happy that the function can return NULL, but in this case it makes perfect sense.

I tried using /*@nullwhenfalse@*/ but it seems to only work if the function returns true/false and also tried to change the code to use a retVal and tried both /*@null@*/ and /*@relnull@*/ in front of the declaration, but these did nothing.

(Just as a side-note, the table is only 20 big atm, so no point in using a clever search algorithm.)

Comment: I think you should a) not declare a pass-by-value argument as "const", but maybe that's your style, and b) include the actual diagnostic output Splint gives you, "not happy" is a bit vague.

Comment: Hm, why shouldn't I declare it const? I like const partly because it makes clear that the value will not be changed by the function.

Comment: OK, OK. I actually realised why you don't like to use const the second I pressed the submit button. A good point, I just automatically add const to all input parameters without considering whether it's pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.

Comment: @unwind The `const int id` argument helps the compiler warn you if you accidentally modify `id`, which is something you can consider desirable (I wouldn't use it, though).

Comment: @Makis the point is that you're not adding it at the same level if you're adding it without considering if it's pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. I consider myself experimented in C and I pause to think each time I use a type qualifier. I wouldn't recommend using them "automatically".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should double check the use of /*@null@*/ in front of the declaration.

In the following compilable version of your example, it does remove the warning (using splint 3.1.2):

```
typedef struct { int id; } MyType_t;
#define NOT_SET -1
#define MY_ARR_SIZE 20
static MyType_t my_arr[MY_ARR_SIZE];

/*@null@*/ static MyType_t *findById(const int id)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MY_ARR_SIZE; i++) {
            if (my_arr[i].id == NOT_SET) {
                    /* Items are sorted so that items with 
                    NOT_SET as ID are at the end of the array */
                    break;
            }
            if (my_arr[i].id == id) {
                    return &(my_arr[i]);
            }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    (void)findById(10);
    return 0;
}
```

If you still have a similar warning, could it be about another part of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

`splint -nullret` will squash that warning (globally) which may or may not be what you want to do. In some cases, unless you are ***sure*** having a type return NULL is correct, you probably *want* the warning.

I tested Jerome's example, and it did hush the warning for that particular function.

Comment: Yes, that would remove the warning, but I don't want to rid of it completely.

Comment: @Makis: Yes, in that case its better to do what Jerome suggests, in fact I've up-voted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, I would strongly suggest not embedding splint codes directly into the source, but instead wrap that functionality in a macro.

For example, over on the Parrot project, I have these macros

```
#  define ARGIN(x)                    /*@in@*/ /*@notnull@*/
#  define ARGIN_NULLOK(x)             /*@in@*/ /*@null@*/
    /* The pointer target must be completely defined before being passed */
    /* to the function. */

#  define ARGOUT(x)                   /*@out@*/ /*@notnull@*/
#  define ARGOUT_NULLOK(x)            /*@out@*/ /*@null@*/
    /* The pointer target will be defined by the function */
```

And then macros are used so we can use:

```
void copy_string( ARGOUT(char *target), ARGIN(const char *source ) ) ...
```

If we want to change how ARGIN() arguments are handled, we change it one place.  We can also support multiple notations for multiple tools or compilers.